# Executing php script with parameter using powershell

Tags: php, powershell, parameter-passing

I am trying to call the `PHP` file by, passing the `request_number` in the localhost URL using `Powershell`

In HTML:

```
<a href='workflow_execution_progress.php?view_id=".$row['request_number']."' title='Click to see the progress of workflow'>
```

I referred to this link but not sure to modify it with parameters.
[Executing php script on powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35134004/executing-php-script-on-powershell)

Update: My PowerShell

```
$PhpExe  = "C:\path\to\php\install\dir\php.exe"
$PhpFile = "C:\path\to\script.php"
$PhpArgs = '-f "{0}"' -f $PhpFile  //args like view_id = 1 / 2 /3 (dynamically)
$PhpOutput = & $PhpExe $PhpArgs
```

Comment: If you call a local PHP file through powershell, then there's not "url" involve (since you're not making a network request).

Comment: yup, it's a local file now. will deploy after the completion of the project. My question is how to pass dynamic id to the PHP file using PowerShell script @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass variable to php script running from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826718/pass-variable-to-php-script-running-from-command-line)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Sorry i am not getting how i can add it in my powershellcode $PhpExe = "C:\path\to\php\install\dir\php.exe" $PhpFile = "C:\path\to\script.php" $PhpArgs = '-f "{0}"' -f $PhpFile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$argv` to get an array of arguments passed to the script.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

```
php script.php arg1 arg2 arg3

<?php
var_dump($argv);
?>

array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "script.php"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "arg1"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "arg2"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "arg3"
}
```

Comment: Sorry i am not getting how i can add it in my powershellcode
$PhpExe  = "C:\path\to\php\install\dir\php.exe" 
$PhpFile = "C:\path\to\script.php"
$PhpArgs = '-f "{0}"' -f $PhpFile

Comment: Maybe I did not understand your problem. I am not sure if it is about how to get the argument passed to the script, or how to pass arguments ?

Comment: Need to pass arguments to the PHP file using powershell script. - how to pass arguments

Comment: I don't get it. I read your update but why not just place arguments after $Phpfile ? $PhpArgs = '-f "{0}"' -f $PhpFile 'view_id=1'